# Collect email and forward - Compile error: Constant expression required

Tags: vba, email, outlook, outlook-2007

I am trying to look for an email that is sent from a specific email address, and then, everyday between 09:00 and 11:00:00, forward all the emails from this specific email address to a second email address.

I'm getting the following error.

[image: Compile error]

```
Sub Search_Inbox()

    Dim myOlApp As New Outlook.Application
    Dim myNameSpace As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim myInbox As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim myitems As Outlook.Items
    Dim myitem As Object
    Dim Found As Boolean 'this is a boolean to check if the code found the emails or not
    Dim Str_Address As String 'this is a String for an Email Address
    Dim Mail_Value As MailItem 'this is where the email adresses will be stored
    Dim Bool_Time As Boolean 'used to hold the time values
    Dim Count As Integer 'used as the count for the array
    Dim emails_forward(Count) As Integer 'used to hold all the emails to be forwarded when it is 11:00


    Set myNameSpace = myOlApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set myInbox = myNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    Set myitems = myInbox.Items
    Found = False

    For Each myitem In myitems
        'below is the selected time period
        If Bool_Time = (Time >= #9:00:00 AM#) And (Time <= #10:59:59 AM#) Then
            If myitem.Class = olMail Then
                If InStr(1, myitem.Mail_Value, "email address to search for") > 0 Then

                    Forward_Emails (Mail_Value)

                    Debug.Print "Found"
                    Found = True
                 End If
            End If
        End If
    Next myitem

End Sub

Function Forward_Emails(Email_to_Forward As Outlook.MailItem)

    Set Email_to_Forward = Item.Forward

    Email_to_Forward.Recipients.Add "email address to forward to after"
    Email_to_Forward.Save


    Email_to_Forward.Send
    Set Email_to_Forward = Nothing

End Function
```

Comment: Your if-statement is wrong in my eyes.

Comment: Appears the line with the error is Dim emails_forward(Count) As Integer. Count does not exist yet but it could if you made it a constant outside of this code. I assume you do not want that, perhaps emails_forward_Count no brackets.

Comment: Declare the array with `ReDim`, example: `ReDim emails_forward(Count) As Integer`

Comment: Thank you so much, the code is working now :)

Answer (score 0):

*Declare the array with `ReDim`, example: `ReDim emails_forward(Count) As Integer`*

***[MSDN Constant expression required](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278723.aspx)***